# Can anyone solve this error in my code to do with calling subs in userform? Error: array or user define expected

Tags: arrays, vba, userform

I want to call different sub depending on what button the user clicks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1 = True Then
    Sort A, B, n
    Exit Sub
ElseIf OptionButton2 = True Then
    Reverse A, B, n
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

The error comes up as "array or user define expected" but i have checked that I have defined the arrays A, B the same throughout my code. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't show us enough context; please use the [edit] link to add more information. Show us the Sort and Reverse methods your code is calling. Which line of code is triggering the error? Also, what values do `A`, `B` and `n` represent? Show us how these are defined.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the property [`value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196172.aspx) of the your option buttons. Currently, you're trying to compare if the button itself (the actual physical control) is true.

For example, if you have a Car and want to check whether or not there is a driver, you would **specifically** check the driver seat and not just look at the entire car or any seat (hopefully this analogy doesn't confuse you).

So with a quick review of your code, it should look like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Sort A, B, n            
    Else
        Reverse A, B, n
    End If
End Sub
```

Also just to help you become a better programmer, use [VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263493%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) for your controls. It helps a lot if someone else has to ever use your code, whether it's a week or a year from now!